# How can I use sessionStorage in web browser on expo

Tags: expo-web

I want to use `sessionStorage` on expo-web development.

How do I access browser based storage with expo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access it as you would in a regular JavaScript project.

```js
sessionStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
```

**Do note**, however, that if you want this code to run both on Web and Native, you will need to make sure `sessionStorage` exists before using it.

```js
const getStoredItem = (key) => window && window.sessionStorage && sessionStorage.getItem(key)
```

This is required because your Expo app **will not** have a `sessionStorage` API once compiled to a native app.

Comment: You mean if there exist a global window object, try to use the sessionStorage? is it right?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I mean that the environment where your app runs is very different whether its on the device as a native app versus in the browser. The presence of the `window` object or even the `window.sessionStorage` object is not guaranteed. Because of this, you always want to check for their existence before trying to use it (like my example above). Otherwise, you risk crashing your app.

Comment: Actually, if you want to see what I mean, just try doing something with `sessionStorage` in your app, then run it in browser and in app. I believe you'll understand better what I mean.

Comment: You might also want to look into using a library like [localForage](https://localforage.github.io/localForage/#localforage). You could then configure it differently based on where you app is running.